# Use file marker with entr

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

I've the following code on `myscript.sh` for the purpose of execute function on a file with `.md` extension when this file is modified:

```
function my_function(){
    echo "I\'ve just seen $1"

}
typeset -fx my_function

find . -name "*.md"  | 
    entr -r -s "my_function $0"
```

[entr documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/entr/entr.1.en.html#DESCRIPTION): * [...] the name of the first file to trigger an event can be read from $0.*

I expect when I change README.md that output will be:
"I've just seen README.md"

In reality when i launch the script and change README.md, following output appears:

```
bash myscript.sh
# output: I've just seen myscript.sh
```

Please, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling entr from a shell script. When the shell performs variable substitution (or [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual), `$0` will expand to the filename of the script. To protect the `$0` from variable substitution by the shell, use `\`:

```
find . -name "*.md" | entr -r -s "my_function \$0"
```

**Edit:** As @roaima reminded, another way is to use single quotes, which protects the entire quoted text:

```
find . -name "*.md" | entr -r -s 'my_function $0'
```

**NB:** If the `SHELL` environment variable is set to something incompatible with bash, `typeset -fx my_function` might not work at all for entr (for example, it doesn't work with `SHELL=/bin/mksh`). Also, consider adding a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to your script, and leaving out the unnecessary word `function`:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_function(){
    echo "I've just seen $1"
}
typeset -fx my_function

find . -name "*.md" |
    entr -r -s "my_function \$0"
```

Comment: Yes, that is an alternative way of doing that.

Comment: @roaima I updated my answer.